# Zip based tax addon in whmcs

Tags: php, whmcs, avalara

i need is zip based tax calculation in WHMCS.

there is only one addon [Avalara AvaTax whmcs](http://www.avalara.com/integrations/whmcs/) for this but this is not what i need.

I need that i can fill tax for zip range..

Answer (score 0):

WHMCS has no capability for tax based on 'zip' only on country and/or state - do the ZIP Codes not apply to a specific state  (in which case the feature you want is part of the standard code).

(yourwhmcsadminurl)/configtax.php